# how to configure QT for Sqlcipher

Tags: sqlite, qt, encryption, sqlcipher

i'm using sqlcipher in cli mode on windows and it works very well. now i'm trying to integrate it into my QT 6.6 project, but it won't work.
I've tried adding the following config to my .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/CODE/QT/sqlcipher/src
LIBS += C:/CODE/QT/sqlcipher/sqlite3.lib
DEFINES += SQLITE_HAS_CODEC
```

hier is my QT code for connecting to sqlcipher

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(mydb.sqlite);
db.open().
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("PRAGMA KEY='ma_phrase_secrete';");
```

but the sql database created with this code can be accessed on sqlitestudio without a password, so the encryption didn't work

Comment: Did you add `QT += sql`?

Comment: yes I did it. I have a config in my .pro that works with sqlite and mysql.

The difficulty is to make it work with sqlcipher. What I need are the specific .pro config or other to make it work with sqlcipher.